# Is it ok to add reference to business object layer in Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, form-authentication

I'm learning to implement security in an asp.net webform application. I'm using simple formauthentication, there's a page (not login) that may allow anonymous visit by checking a token from url and see if it's existing in database table.
After researching online, my current solution is:

**web.config:**

- general form authentication

  ```
  <authentication mode="Forms" >
  ```
- allow anonymous user to visit specific page

  ```
  <location path="MyPage.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  ```

**Global.asax:**

- call method in business object layer to check if the token is valid
  in database

  ```
  protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      bool auth = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
      if (!auth)
      {
          string token = Request.QueryString["token"];
          var authenticateResult = AuthenticateBO.AuthenticateProductRequest(token);
      }
  }
  ```

I see some posts online that doesn't recommend to call database connection in application level. I'm wondering in my case (need to check token in database), can I add business layer reference in Global.asax? Or is there any better solution? Thanks!

Comment: Definitely NOT OK to reference your UI from the BLL - its UI -> BLL -> DAL. also there would be no benefit for the BLL To have access to Global.asax.cs methods

Comment: If you are calling a business layer method, and that method internally accessing DB, that should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Arghya C said, looks like you are using a Business Object to check if your token is valid. If this method access your database or not it`s up to your Business Layer to decide.

The important thing to notice here is that your Global.asax does not know nothing about database, and this shows that your implementation has a good separation, it is not possible to know that you are authenticating against a database if you didn't said.